# AngularJS DatePicker value is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Im trying to pass the date from a date picker value into a $http session parameter (like "2017-12-7"), but the date my datepicker Date variable is 'undefined'

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('MyController',
            function($scope, $http) {                   

                  this.myDate = new Date();
                  this.minDate = new Date("December 4, 2017");
                  this.maxDate = new Date("December 10, 2017");

                  $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {

                      var dt = this.myDate;

                        $http({

                            method : 'GET',
                            url : 'myurl',
                            params : {
                                pdate : this.myDate
                            }
                        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                            $scope.datacontainer= response.data;
                        }, function myError(response) {

                        });
                    };

        });
```

The **$scope.getDataFromServer** method is called when you click a button. 
The following line **var dt = this.myDate;** was to look at the myDate object in chrome DevTools (F12) and it says 'undefined'.

The date picker HTML is as follows:

```
<div flex="20">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="ctrl.minDate" md-max-date="ctrl.maxDate">
  </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: try preserving parent this before using  like `var myContext = this;` and get `myContext.myDate`

Comment: @beaumondo - You probably defined the controller like `MyApp as ctrl` in the view, so you need to set the modal like this: `ng-model="ctrl.myDate"`. In the controller itself, put on the very top line of the controller function this: `var ctrl = this;` and then change all the current `this` and `$scope` to `ctrl` so your code will be more readable. Don't forget the add the `ctrl.` prefix for any other controller properties in the VIEW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.myDate` is evaluated to undefined here because `this` is in different context when `getDataFromServer` is executed. The problem here is you have initialized `myDate` inside `MyController` and function is defined inside `$scope`. Read more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers).

`getDataFromServer` cannot see `myDate` as its created inside `MyController`.

**Solution:**

Define them both in same context.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('MyController',
        function($scope, $http) {                   
              var ctrl = this;
              ctrl.myDate = new Date();
              ctrl.minDate = new Date("December 4, 2017");
              ctrl.maxDate = new Date("December 10, 2017");

              ctrl.getDataFromServer = function() {

                  var dt = ctrl.myDate;

                    $http({

                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'myurl',
                        params : {
                            pdate : ctrl.myDate
                        }
                    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                        ctrl.datacontainer= response.data;
                    }, function myError(response) {

                    });
                };

    });
```

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var ctrl =this;
  ctrl.myDate = new Date();
  ctrl.value="No Date Selected";
  ctrl.getDataFromServer = function() {
    ctrl.value = ctrl.myDate;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.js"></script>

<md-content ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs="">
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="ctrl.getDataFromServer()">Print</md-button>
  </div>
  {{ctrl.value}}
</md-content>
```

Comment: I would recommend to save a reference to `this` at the first line of the controller (i.e `var ctrl = this;` or `var vm = this;`) and use that reference throughout the controller, this will ensure that you don't lose the reference to the controller in inner functions, so you could change `$scope.datacontainer= response.data;` to `ctrl.datacontainer= response.data;` in the success callback of the ajax call

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for suggestion. Modified answer to reflect the changes.`this` reference is one of the easily confused aspect of JS.

Comment: Good call, solution worked well. I thought because it was a nested function inside the controller all local variable were accessible

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('MyController',
        function($scope, $http) {                   
              var that = this;
              that.myDate = new Date();
              that.minDate = new Date("December 4, 2017");
              that.maxDate = new Date("December 10, 2017");

              $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
                  var dt = that.myDate;

                    $http({

                        method : 'GET',
                        url : 'myurl',
                        params : {
                            pdate : that.myDate
                        }
                    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                        $scope.datacontainer = response.data;
                    }, function myError(response) {

                    });
                };

    });
```

Comment: What is this, an answer or what? Read [answer], explain what you changed, the OP is not supposed to guess your explanation. And BTW, you have a bug in your answer, and it shouldn't solve anything at all